# How to print pattern shown in the image attached using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

[Output I want and Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vn82.png) 
Please see the image I wanted to print a similar pattern and I am succeeded to some extent. I am not able to get rid of similar addends like 1 4 and 4 1. I only need 4 1 and I didn't want 1 4 to be printed.
Can anyone suggest some modification to my code to achieve the desired output?

**MY CODE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 5;
    partition(n);
}

 public static void partition(int n) {
    partition(n, 1, "" );
}

public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i <= n; i++) {
        partition(n-i, i, prefix + i + " ");
    }
}
```

please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem in *recursion* but rather *iteration*.  Given the loop in the recursive starting code you linked:

```
for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
    partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + i);
}
```

We just need to make that loop run *backwards*:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.min(max, n); i++) {
    partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + i);
}
```

The complete source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Partition {

    public static void partition(int n) {
        partition(n, n, "");
    }

    public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.min(max, n); i++) {
            partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        partition(n);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> java Partition
5
 1 1 1 1 1
 2 1 1 1
 2 2 1
 3 1 1
 3 2
 4 1
 5
>
```

I believe you were making the problem harder than it is.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a recursive solution yet, but this should do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int[] arr = new int[n]; 
    int[] idx = new int[n];
    int currSize = n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {arr[i] = 1; idx[i] = i + 1;}
    
    while(true) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i = idx[i]) System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        
        boolean changed = false;
        
        for(int i = 0; idx[i] < n; i = idx[i]){
            if(arr[i] == arr[idx[i]]){
                arr[i]++;
                arr[idx[i]]--;
                if(arr[idx[i]] == 0) {
                    idx[i] = idx[idx[i]];
                    currSize--;
                }
                changed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(!changed && currSize > 1){
            arr[0]++;
            arr[idx[0]]--;
            if(arr[idx[0]] == 0) {
                idx[0] = idx[idx[0]];
                currSize--;
                if(currSize == 1) {
                    System.out.println(arr[0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 1 1 1 1 
2 1 1 1 
2 2 1 
3 1 1 
3 2 
4 1 
5
```

Comment: thanks for your help daniel but the program should be able to print the similar pattern for different values of n = N where N (1 ≤ N ≤ 40)

Comment: eg: for n = 6 it should display \n
 1 1 1 1 1 1 \n
 2 1 1 1 1 \n
 2 2 1 1 \n
 2 2 2 \n
 3 1 1 1 \n
 3 2 1 \n
 3 3 \n
 4 1 1 \n
 4 2 \n
 5 1 \n
 6

Comment: Then you should explain the logic of the pattern. Why would `2 2 1 1` become `2 2 2` and not `3 1 1 1`?

Comment: see this for logic: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Partition.java.html